# lndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, range

I need to generate a string from random letters given in list take_from. The first time the function was executed it generated a phrase but all my following tries prompted an error "list index out of range". I can`t understand this error in my case and I tried while loop instead of for loop but it did not work either.

```
from random import randint

def make_a_phrase():
    random_string = ''
    take_from = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l',
                'm','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','v','u','w','x',
                'y','z',' ']
    for i in range(28):
        random_string = random_string + take_from[randint
                                    (0,len(take_from))]
    return random_string
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, lists are indexed with integers ranging from 0 to 1 less than the length of the list. E.g., a list with 10 items in it would have indexes from 0 to 9.

Your call to `randint()` attempts to get indexes from zero to the full length of the list, which will cause this exception. Change it to:

```
for i in range(28):
    random_string = random_string + take_from[randint
                                    (0,len(take_from)-1)]
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint)

> random.randint(a, b)
>    Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b.
>   Alias for randrange(a, b+1).

Therefore you can get values from 0 to `len(take_from)` - **inclusive the endpoints** - which in case of the upper bound would be out of list's index range as it is zero based and as such only has `len(take_from) - 1` elements

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens, is because the `len` returns the length, but the last index is always the length - 1 (since indices start from 0).

So eventually, the random integer that comes up is the length, and of course, there is no element at that number.

Here is a simple example:

```
>>> i = [1,2,3]
>>> len(i)
3
>>> i[len(i)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

However, if you -1 from the length you will get the last item:

```
>>> i[len(i)-1]
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your loop to say:

```
for i in range(0, len(take_from)):
```

You are currently experiencing an off-by-one error because you only have 27 elements in your list, not 28.

Comment: The error comes from `random.randint()` which will use `len(take_from)` itself as a possible integer. It's not due to the `for i` loop because she never attempts to use `i` as an index.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this instead

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
import random

def make_a_phrase():
    return ''.join(random.choice(ascii_lowercase + ' ') for i in range(28))
```